# Trouble converting SQL Query into JPQL (Eclipselink)

Tags: java, jpa, aggregate-functions, eclipselink, jpql

Hey guys,  I have the following query and for the life of me I can't seem to translate it into JPQL.  The working SQL is:

```
select * from TB_PRINT_DETAIL y inner join 
(select JOB_ID,max(COPY_NUM) MAX_COPY_NUM from TB_PRINT_DETAIL  group by JOB_ID  ) x
on y.JOB_ID = x.JOB_ID and y.COPY_NUM = x.MAX_COPY_NUM
```

My feeble attempt at translating it is as follows:

```
select o from PrintDetailEntity o inner join (select o2.jobId, max(o2.copyNumber) as
maxCopyNum from PrintDetailEntity o2 group by o2.jobId ) as x on o.jobId = o2.jobId and
o.copyNum = o2.maxCopyNum where o.printSuppressionReasonEntity is null
```

Thanks in advance for any light you can shine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query right (select entities that have the biggest `copyNumber` among the entites with the same `jobId`), the following should work:

```
SELECT o 
FROM PrintDetailEntity o 
WHERE o.copyNumber = 
    (SELECT MAX(e.copyNumber) FROM PrintDetailEntity e WHERE o.jobId = e.jobId)
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I don't know why I was having such trouble with that.